# why a decoder of the VAE can generate reasonable outpouts using normal distribution samples?

Tags: autoencoder

I am struggling to understand how the decoder of variational autoencoder (VAE) works, and there is a question still making me confused after reading some papers and doing some researches, which is as following : 
   why the decoder of a trained VAE can generate reasonable outputs just using the samples from Normal distribution instead of the samples from distribution  generated by the encoder,which is denoted by q(z|x) in most academic papers. 
   in other words, The KL divergence does his job by pulling the q(z|x) towards the Normal distribution during the VAE training. Nevertheless, there is no way that the q(z|x) is strictly identical to the Normal distribution when the training is done. 
   so in the procedure of training, the inputs of decoder are the samples from distribution q(z|x),which is the output of encoder. 
    My question is : why the decoder can generate the outputs reasonably just using the samples from the Normal distribution, insteading of using ones from the distribution q(z|x),when the training is done.

Any tips and hints will be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The question was asked more than a year ago but in the spirit of better late than never here is how to reason about it based on use cases -

a) If your use case is to re-construct your input then you would go the route of first feeding your image to the encoder, get the approximate posterior, then sample from it and feed that latent sample to the decoder. If you have a well-trained network then you would get the output which is similar/same as your input. But then what is the utility of this in the first place? See use case (c) to see when having an encoder is important/interesting.

b) Let's remove the encoder from VAE. You have a trained decoder that accepts z. In other words, it is capable of mapping the z to an image. Since the z that it was trained with earlier was **approximately** standard normal, the decoder will generate the corresponding image. This generated image will now be considered synthetic and wouldn't necessarily match any of your training data.

c) There is another VAE called CVAE (Conditioned Variational Encoder) which has the same flow as regular VAE with the addition that you can supply extra input (i.e besides the latent sample). This additional input would then influence the generation/reconstruction of the input. For e.g. you pass in an image to the encoder to get the z, you then supply a (learned) vector that represents the addition of glasses and pass this vector and z to the decoder. Now the result will be the same/similar to the image you passed as input to the encoder but with the addition of glasses.

> My question is: why the decoder can generate the outputs reasonably just using the samples from the Normal distribution

I have answered in use case (b) but to be very explicit here - The reason decoder can generate the outputs reasonably because it was trained with input (z in this case) that is sampled from a distribution closer to standard normal.

Comment: Thank you ksachdeva. it is really helpful.